# Redirect root domain to sub folder file without displaying path in address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

My symfony project is in public_html/web/app.php
What I want is to redirect all requests on my site example.com to open app.php in that path without displaying the full path in address bar.
i.e. though file path will be example.com/web/app.php all user should see is example.com in address bar.

Comment: as u mentioned in your tag htaccess also perform this task

Comment: A default symfony project already includes the required htacces file. You only need to setup your hosting to use `/web` as the web root directory.

Comment: i tried htaccess. surfed through net and did what others have done.. what worked for them is not working for me

Comment: @Yoshi seems i cant  do that as well. I tried add on domains , redirects everything..

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should probably not try to solve this with your symfony project, but rather with the tools your hosting environment gives you. Try looking for a configuration option to define the document/web-root folder.

Comment: Nope. i bought hosting from local merchant in my country.. and got credentials.

Comment: I see, well, then as I said, try looking for a way to configure your exposed web-root. Though, it could of course be that, depending on the package you bought, you are not allowed to change this. If so, you'll probably be better of, looking for another service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your public_html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ /web/app.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: already tried a lot of things.. nothing works. this does not work as well. it still points to public_html

Comment: i have created index.html in public_html folder with some content.. after i type the url. i try open index.html the file which is located in public_html is opening up

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htaccess file?

Comment: 'code' RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.hamrosahitya\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hamrosahitya.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /app.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hamrosahitya.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

'code' RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1

Comment: Do you want to redirect all incomming requests (including existing files and dirs) to /web/app.php ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Yoshi pointed out in the comments, you need to set the DocumentRoot of your site to **.../public_html/web**, and **not** to **../public_html**.

If that is correct, you should be able to surf your app as:

```
example.com/app.php
```

After that, you can use the mentioned .htaccess rules to redirect and remove the "app.php" part.

That is the standard Symfony configuration. If you want to do something unusual and put Symfony in a subfolder of an existing site, that is a different question that has already been answered: [How can I deploy Symfony in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426989/how-can-i-deploy-symfony-in-a-subdirectory/31437670#31437670)