# Run Symfony3 project folder in Shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I am new to Symfony with shared hosting.

Installed a symfony using Cpanel app installer option and made a page called about and its working like **www.domain.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/about** but i want to know how to make that like following **www.domain.com/symfony/about** How do that possible?

i wrote .htaccess like below but no success,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /symfony/web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens if you delete your .htaccess, and try to go to www.domain.com/symfony/about?
Do you have SSH access?

Comment: i am getting "Internal Server Error" and SSH access yes and what i do through that?

Comment: I think you can find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426989/how-can-i-deploy-symfony-in-a-subdirectory
Extra info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Apache on the shared hosting (it's the most common).

The problem here is that your document root for your site is set to the directory two levels above the app_dev.php file.

You should add a subdomain for your app that points to your symfony/web folder as the root. You can find [documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Subdomains) on configuring subdomains in cPanel. Once that's running you should hopefully be able to access your app at symfony.yourdomain.com

Comment: i tried your way by adding addon domain and its working around 50% need but another page should work like www.domain.com/about now its coming like www.domain.com/app_dev.php/about

Comment: Updated with following .htaccess but no use
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule> `

Comment: I think your rewrite rules needs to point to app_dev.php check the default symfony one

Comment: Sorry, can't understand. and there is no .htaccess file default.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess) is the default Symfony .htaccess file

Comment: Ok, In this file where i can set redirection ?

Comment: I thought your problem now was just app_dev.php appearing in the URL. The default .htaccess file should fix this if you put it in your web folder

Comment: I have done included .htaccess in the web/ folder but nothing happen its till same.

Answer (score 0):

Using default .htaccess, you should be able to reach `www.domain.com/symfony/web/about`

To override the web directory, you can use this .htaccess on your base dir (same level with composer.json, etc)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Also, you want to make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enable on your PHP conf.

Comment: Where the .htacess file show be ? www.domain.com/symfony/.htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Default .htaccess provided by Symfony work for everything except the base /web/ override, since it may change, depending on your web hosting

Comment: i tried but no success, i am seeing 404 when i view www.domain.com/symfony and working when i see www.domain.com/symfony/web