# How to fix unable to detect the front controller, disabling the PHP server error="Passthru script index.php does not exist under /Users

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, front-controller

[  unable to detect the front controller, disabling the PHP server error="Passthru script "/index.php"] does not exist under /Users/local/Desktop/portofolio/[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwgOx.jpg)

This is the index.php

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TKoX.jpg)

[here is my application tree structure, the index.php is in the public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4uh0.jpg)

[in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsBcC.jpg)

hello,

I encountered this error after generating a sylius project, since all my symfony projects include (the sylius project that cause this error) have this problem.
Will anyone know a lead to fix this bug?

Comment: pretty much the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31437670/6127393 (public used to be called web)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I deploy Symfony in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426989/how-can-i-deploy-symfony-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: it helped me to switch to another folder. `~/synf/my-synf-app$ symfony server:start`